# What are the differences between normal version and director's cut version of episode 6?

Tags: gurren-lagann

According to [Wikipedia - List of Gurren Lagann episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Gurren_Lagann_episodes), episode 6 has 2 versions:

- The normal version which is first aired on May 6, 2007 in Japan, titled

  **"Sit in the Hot Tub 'Till You're Sick!!" (てめえら全員湯あたりしやがれ!!)**
- The director's cut version, which is released on DVD, having a different title

  **"There are Some Things I Just Have to See!!" (見てえものは見てえんだ!!)**

What are the differences between the 2 versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_6):

> The uncut version of this episode features more explicity such as:
>
> - More of Yoko's breasts are revealed. At the end of the episode, her top falls off completely-although we still don't see anything.
> - Gimmy's penis is briefly shown. (This is actually not seen as taboo in Japan, as Gimmy is considered too young to be sexualized.)
>
> Scenes added include:
>
> - Kamina trying to peek at the girls.
> - The beastmen fool Kamina into giving up Gurren-by offering to remove the pixellation seemingly covering their nudity. (Of course, they
>     aren't actually naked-just wearing tiny, skin-tinted swimsuits.)
> - The beastmen using a shock collar-like device on the girls.